# how to read object from file of different base class objects in cpp

Tags: c++

want to store different shape objects into file and read the same using cpp. please help me how to do ?

```
    static void saveShape(Shape* shape)//Shape may be circle, square, rectangle.....
    {
        ofstream os;
        os.open("shapetemp.txt", ios::app);
        os << shape;
        os.close(); 
    }
    static void readShape()
    {
        Shape tempShape ;
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("shapetemp.txt",ios::in);
        while ( ??)
        {
            //what is code to write here??
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: You will have to read the actual type from the file, not just the base class.

Comment: i want to store different shape objects like rectangle, square ,circle..into file and to read the same using cpp

Comment: @Tyro read about boost::serialization

Comment: SO is not a code writing service - you need to try something yourself (e.g.: using a search engine to find some of the existing examples that already do it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use protobuf save you data

```
message PBDataContainer {
    Any data = 1;
}
```

the any type will save type info of the real data, you can read the data, and parser by protobuf